# IE 11 problems opening localhost

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, visual-studio-debugging, internet-explorer-11

I can not figure this out, I've been writing web sites for a while now and never ran into anything like this.  I am debugging a .Net MVC web application and trying to get to it in Internet Explorer 11.  When I type in   `http://localhost:4718` or `localhost:4718` I get the error

> "No apps are installed to open this type of link(localhost)"

I am positive port 4718 is what I want it works in every other browser .  This is just an IE 11 with Windows 8 thing that I can not figure out.  I saw in another question to disable "Enable Enhanced Protection Mode" in advanced settings. This did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing `localhost:4718` makes IE think that you're trying to open a protocol that is coincidentally named `localhost`. Thus you should always use the longer form `http://localhost:4718/` or at least `//localhost:4718/`.

You absolutely shouldn't be seeing the same error for the full URL; if you are, go to a command prompt and type `ping localhost` and copy its results in your question.